# inner_hits does not work for nested filters when searching multiple indices

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

**Elasticsearch version**
Version: 6.2.2

I'm trying to search multiple indices which both have nested objects. To keep it simple I will use this example. In the query I use "inner_hits" property.

```
PUT /sales
{
    "mappings": {
        "_doc" : {
            "properties" : {
                "tags" : { "type" : "keyword" },
                "comments" : { 
                    "type" : "nested",
                    "properties" : {
                        "username" : { "type" : "keyword" },
                        "comment" : { "type" : "text" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

PUT /sales/_doc/1?refresh
{
    "tags": ["car", "auto"],
    "comments": [
        {"username": "baddriver007", "comment": "This car could have better brakes"},
        {"username": "dr_who", "comment": "Where's the autopilot? Can't find it"},
        {"username": "ilovemotorbikes", "comment": "This car has two extra wheels"}
    ]
}

PUT /markets
{
    "mappings": {
        "_doc" : {
            "properties" : {
                "name" : { "type" : "keyword" },
                "products" : { 
                    "type" : "nested",
                    "properties" : {
                        "name" : { "type" : "keyword" },
                        "sku" : { "type" : "text" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

POST /sales,markets/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "comments",
                  "inner_hits": {

                  },
                  "ignore_unmapped": true,
                  "query": {
                    "match_all": {}
                  }
                }   
              }]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "products",
                  "inner_hits": {

                  },
                  "ignore_unmapped": true,
                  "query": {
                    "match_all": {}
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So this query gives an error

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_state_exception",
        "reason": "[match_all] no mapping found for type [comments]"
      },
      {
        "type": "illegal_state_exception",
        "reason": "[match_all] no mapping found for type [products]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "markets",
        "node": "-22psoQNRLa8_Y9GeHBXaw",
        "reason": {
          "type": "illegal_state_exception",
          "reason": "[match_all] no mapping found for type [comments]"
        }
      },
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "sales",
        "node": "-22psoQNRLa8_Y9GeHBXaw",
        "reason": {
          "type": "illegal_state_exception",
          "reason": "[match_all] no mapping found for type [products]"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

But when I add "ignore_unmapped": true inside each "inner_hits": { "ignore_unmapped": true } everything works fine. This is not implemented in NEST .net library.

Is it right to use "ignore_unmapped" inside "inner_hits", because I didn't find this as "inner_hits" property in the documentation ?
Is there any other solution in NEST for this to be done.

**UPDATE**:

I tried using operator overloading queries and I got

```
Func<SearchDescriptor<object>, ISearchRequest> search = s => s.Type<object>()
                .Index(Indices.Index("sales", "markets"))
                .AllTypes()
                .Explain(false)
                .Query(q => (q
                    .Nested(n => n
                                .IgnoreUnmapped(true)
                                .Path(Infer.Field<SaleDocument>(f => f.Comments))
                                .InnerHits(ih => ih
                                    .Size(1)
                                )
                                .Query(q1 => q1
                                    .MatchAll()
                                )
                    ) && +q.Terms(t => t
                        .Field("_index")
                        .Terms(new[] { "sales" })
                    )
                ) || (q
                    .Nested(n => n
                        .IgnoreUnmapped(true)
                        .Path(Infer.Field<MarketDocument>(f => f.Products))
                        .InnerHits(ih => ih
                            .Size(1)
                        )
                        .Query(q1 => q1
                            .MatchAll()
                        )
                    ) && +q.Terms(t => t
                            .Field("_index")
                            .Terms(new[] { "markets" })
                        )
                )
            );
```

This code created query

```
POST /sales,markets/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "explain": false,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "query": {
                    "match_all": {}
                  },
                  "path": "comments",
                  "inner_hits": {
                    "size": 1
                  },
                  "ignore_unmapped": true
                }
              }
            ],
            "filter": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "_index": [
                    "sales"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "query": {
                    "match_all": {}
                  },
                  "path": "products",
                  "inner_hits": {
                    "size": 1
                  },
                  "ignore_unmapped": true
                }
              }
            ],
            "filter": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "_index": [
                    "markets"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Which again gives error

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_state_exception",
        "reason": "[match_all] no mapping found for type [comments]"
      },
      {
        "type": "illegal_state_exception",
        "reason": "[match_all] no mapping found for type [products]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "markets",
        "node": "-22psoQNRLa8_Y9GeHBXaw",
        "reason": {
          "type": "illegal_state_exception",
          "reason": "[match_all] no mapping found for type [comments]"
        }
      },
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "sales",
        "node": "-22psoQNRLa8_Y9GeHBXaw",
        "reason": {
          "type": "illegal_state_exception",
          "reason": "[match_all] no mapping found for type [products]"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say, it looks like `inner_hits` property is missing within NEST; I'll open an issue to add this for the next release now.

`ignore_unmapped` is the way to handle this when needing `inner_hits`. If you didn't need `inner_hits`, you could combine each nested query with a `term` query on the `"_index"` metadata field that targets the respective index name in each case, such that the nested query is run only against the indices that contain the target field.

Comment: I see you've already added https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/3132, Thank you :)

Comment: Hi Russ, thanks for your response. I tried adding the filter after should query that contains nested query, `"should": [... { "nested": {..} }], "filter": { "term": { "_index": "sales" } }`. I also tried inside `"nested": {..."query": {"bool": { "filter": { "term": {"_index": "sales" }}}}}`, but I get the same error. Can you point out where it should be in my code ?

Comment: @GavrilOgnjanovski you'd want to combine the `term` queries on the `_index` metadata field similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/45516969/1831. Essentially, `&&` each `term` query to each nested query, and prefix with unary `+` to ensure it becomes a `bool` filter clause. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html for operator overloading on queries

Comment: I updated my answer with the NEST .net code and the error. I still get error when I try to get the `inner_hits`

Comment: [NestedQueryBuilder.java](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/5263b8cc7ee7b1a52880ab98587b88d6c00557b8/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/NestedQueryBuilder.java). Can this code on line 345 be a problem ? `if (innerHitBuilder.isIgnoreUnmapped() == false) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("[" + query.getName() + "] no mapping found for type [" + path + "]");`

Comment: Is it possible that the version of ElasticSearch (6.2.2) that I'm using is the problem. Maybe I should use older version ?

Comment: @GavrilOgnjanovski I've been able to confirm that the issue here is related to `inner_hits` collection; I'll open a PR for the addition of `ignore_unmapped`

Comment: I already made pull request on Github and fix it, no need to duplicate it.

Comment: @GavrilOgnjanovski I opened one before I saw your PR.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in both places and will be available in some of the future releases of NEST or ElasticSearch.

1. NEST .net library by adding `IgnoreUnmapped()` method in InnerHits.
   https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/3132
2. Elastic Search by inherit `ignore_unmapped` in `inner_hits` from nested query `ignore_unmapped` property
   https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/29071